# LensKit recommendation without rating

Tags: recommendation-engine, lenskit

I try to implement a recommendation engine with LensKit 3.0 in a Java webapp for an ecommerce website. I would like to generate recommendations for a given user according to purchase history, therefore I only have implicit events of 'buy' and 'view'.

According to the [documentation](https://lenskit.gitbooks.io/lenskit-manual/cookbook/implicit-feedback.html), I bind RatingVectorPDAO to EntityCountRatingVectorPDAO, but how will it be used during the build of the engine?